# Can I display a standard button based on the app selected?

Tags: page-layout, standard-objects, configuration, sales-cloud

I have a requirement that when the user selects the Sales app, the New button on the opportunity detail page should be visible, but when any other app is selected, the New Button should not be displayed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're on lightning:

You have the ability to create Lightning record pages which allows you to specify assignments based on the following combination:

- App
- Record Type
- Profile

Unfortunately, this only helps you with the things that the Lightning record pages control which is the UI of the page, components on page, page template, etc.

Controlling buttons on a layout are still on the **page layouts** (the details that display on a lightning record page) which are still **assigned on a per profile basis.**

I'm not seeing a way you could achieve this as of this moment to apply to one app but not another as the same underlying *page layout* would be applied in each app.

They have prioritized the idea to [deliver dynamic page layouts](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brox) and anticipate it coming in Winter 21. I'm not sure it would really apply to this situation, but it's possible they start adding the ability to customize more on these layouts for different criteria as you need in the coming releases.